# run gradle test suit through jenkins: where do dependencies download

Tags: jenkins, testing, gradle, automation

When a gradle test script is run through jenkins, should dependencies be downloaded to a folder?
When i run on my laptop i use MavenLocal in the build.gradle and every dependency is present in the .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your dependencies will be downloaded from public repositories that you configured in the gradle script, e.g. mavenCentral() or jcenter().

If you have your own libraries, which cannot be downloaded from any public repository, you have to push them to your personal repository first, e.g. [Nexus](https://de.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss). After creating a user on Nexus, you set up the credentials in jenkins and [pass them as environment variables to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562224/how-do-i-pass-jenkins-credentials-to-gradle).